# Mac M1 Monterey Homebrew-installed PHP Not Running

Tags: php, macos, apache

I used Homebrew to install Apache and PHP on a new Mac Studio. When I run

```
apachectl configtest
```

I get:

Syntax Ok.

When I run

```
Php -v
```

I get:

PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 12 2022 23:30:39) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v8.1.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

In https.conf, I put:

```
ServerName 10.0.4.65:8080 

LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

I also added:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

And at the end of the file:

```
<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

The phpinfo.php displayed correctly.

I then installed XDebug and now PHP doesn’t run. It now shows:

phpinfo();

Google has not found me an answer to this issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: And what happens if you uninstall XDebug?

Comment: It works again. My apologies. I should have been more clear that I was also interested in understanding why it broke.

Comment: right, so then the actual question is, __"Why does XDebug break PHP on MacOS Monterey"__? Please also add your Apache version here.